PhD 'transfer' application: What to disclose?
I'm an international student in the US and I have just finished my 2nd year in a PhD program at University A. During my coursework, my research interests evolved significantly and they're not aligned anymore with faculty expertise in my department. I have expressed my wish to apply elsewhere in the US in order to 'continue' my PhD in a more suitable environment and my supervisor and committee have been supportive. My current PhD program doesn't award MA degrees. However, another department I've worked with very closely offered to give me an MS under a few conditions that are irrelevant here. (NB: By the time I graduate, I will have received a full ride from both programs).
As I will likely leave University A with a Master's degree, should I explain in my application (statement of purpose, etc.) how I transitioned from a PhD in one department to a Master's in another? Or should I avoid doing this and work on my applications as if I were a 'regular' master's student instead?
P.S. I know there's no such thing as 'continuing' or 'transferring' a PhD at another University per se, but for the sake of brevity I thought it best to use this vocabulary!

As usual, tell the truth. Will your 'supportive' advisor and committee provide letters of reference? Well, they will tell the truth.

Thank you, @JonCuster. Yes, they will provide letters. Lying is definitely not what I was thinking of when I wrote this post, although I understand that omission can be just as problematic. As many do, I'm probably worrying too much about people (admission committees in this case) reacting negatively to what they may label a 'failure', especially in very competitive programs.

I recommend that you "tell all" though the SoP isn't the place for it. If you have reasons for your actions there is no need to hide anything. And most such educational activities leave some sort of paper trail that can be discovered. If you hide parts of it you will raise questions and possibly be subject to disciplinary action.
People will, in general, be aware that individuals have various pathways through the educational system and may be limited by choices and decisions made by others. Navigating a difficult course is admirable.
But keep the SoP focused on your educational and research goals, not on difficulties or things you think might be failures that must be explained.
